# Querying based on a data entered in an Access form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've trying to build a query that will look at various fields that are filled out in an associated form. In particular, I'm looking to query for all records > a certain date. This column in the database is stored as a DateTime. Right now, my query looks as follows: (Note that fromDate is just a textbox.

```
SELECT * FROM ACM_TABLE where DT_TM>[Forms]![Form1]!fromDate
```

When I replace this with a hardcoded date in the form mm/dd/yyyy, it returns results, but querying based on what is entered in the form does not. Is there some type of conversion I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: How does Access see the value of *fromDate*?  Paste this into SQL View of a new query, run it, and see how Access responds: `SELECT Forms!Form1!fromDate AS the_value, TypeName(Forms!Form1!fromDate) AS TypeOf_value, IsDate(Forms!Form1!fromDate) AS value_is_date`

Comment: It shows as a string. I tried converting this into a Date using the CDate function, but now it says the expression is too complex to be evaluated. Is there a way to change this in the form so its a proper date?

Comment: I can't see what you see.  So I suggest you open the form in Design View, select that text box, open its property sheet, and select the "Format" tab on the property sheet.  Then, in the Format dropdown, select General Date or Short Date.  Save the form design.  Close it.  Reopen the form and enter a date into the text box.  Click on another control in the form.  Then re-run the query from my first comment.  If it shows you "Date" for TypeOf_value and -1 (True) for value_is_date, try your original query again and tell us what happens.

Comment: Ah I got it. Turns out Access didn't like me changing the field to a short date, but seems to have taken general date just fine. Thanks for the help. I apologize if this seems like a silly question, but hopefully someone else might run into something similar

Comment: It's fundamental, not silly.  This type of issue perplexes many people.  It makes more sense when you investigate how Access actually "sees" the value.  Then you just have to figure out how to make Access see it as you want.  :-)  Please submit an answer which explains your solution.  TIA.